# What is needed to use a HP Deskjet printer bought in Canada, in Hong Kong?

Tags: printer

My aunt must bring her 2012 HP Deskjet 3510,  bought in Canada, to Hong Kong where she'll be working. She has checked that the AC Power Adapter states "100-240V" [as beneath](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-AC-Adapter-Power-Cord-Charger-For-HP-Deskjet-3056A-3510-3511-3512-Printer/272195266294?epid=10020029382&hash=item3f601a26f6:g:O8UAAOSwFnxbmKq5).

[image]

1. What's the cord pinpointed with the red arrow called? Does she need to bring it?
2. Does she simply attach a [plug adapter](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/information-for-travellers/) to the end of the red-arrowed cord? Or must she buy another cord like it, but for 220V?

Comment: The same equipment can be used as is. A plug adapter may be needed (I don't know the standards for HK, if the same as mainland China then typically US plugs fit).

Comment: Hong Kong is not the same as the US. See [IEC - World Plugs](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/). An Adapter will be needed (or just buy a new mains cable in any computer shop)

Comment: [Electricity and Voltage | Hong Kong Tourism Board](https://www.discoverhongkong.com/uk/plan-your-trip/traveller-info/good-to-know/electricity-and-voltage.jsp) "The majority of electrical outlets in Hong Kong take a three-pronged UK-style plug."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hong Kong Power Outlets

> What's the cord pinpointed with the red arrow called?

It's an AC Power Cord - either an [IEC 320 C7 (non-polarized)](https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/power#c7-non-polarized) or an [IEC 320 C7 (polarized)](https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/power#c7-polarized) - cannot be sure from your image.

> Does she need to bring it? Does she simply attach a plug adapter to the end of the red-arrowed cord?

She can either bring it and buy an appropriate adapter (Canada to UK Plug Adapter), or just buy a new cable with the correct plug from any computer shop.

See [IEC - World Plugs](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/) for more information on plugs in different countries.

> Must she buy another cord like it, but for 220V?

No. Her adapter is already rated for 100-240V. Hong Hong is 220V.

[Electricity and Voltage | Hong Kong Tourism Board](https://www.discoverhongkong.com/uk/plan-your-trip/traveller-info/good-to-know/electricity-and-voltage.jsp):

> The standard electrical voltage in Hong Kong is 220 volts AC, 50Hz.

...

> The majority of electrical outlets in Hong Kong take a three-pronged UK-style plug. You can buy an inexpensive adapter for your electrical equipment at most convenience stores.